# How to re-use a view to update objects in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get my head around Class based views (I'm new to Django). I currently have a project that uses function based views. My 'create' view renders a form and successfully submits to the database. However, I need an edit/update function so the obvious option is to re-use the 'create' function I made but I'm struggling to work it out and adhere to the DRY principle.

Is using Class based views the right way to go?
Do they handle the creation of all the 'CRUD' views?

I'm currently working my way through the [GoDjano](https://godjango.com/15-class-based-views-part-1-templateview-and-redirectview/) tutorials on Class based views but its still not sinking in.

Any help/pointers would be, as usual, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L193), a `CreateView` and an `UpdateView` are very similar. The only difference is that a `CreateView` sets `self.object` to `None`, forcing the creation of a new object, while `UpdateView` sets it to the updated object.

Creating a `UpdateOrCreateView` would be as simple as subclassing `UpdateView` and overriding the `get_object` method to return `None`, should a new object be created.

```
class UpdateOrCreateView(UpdateView):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        # or any other condition
        if not self.kwargs.get('pk', None):
            return None
        return super(UpdateOrCreateView, self).get_object(queryset)
```

The GoDjango tutorials don't seem to be out of date (CBVs have barely changed since their introduction), but they do seem to be missing some of the essential views in their tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

CBV is in my opinion *never* the solution. A dry FBV is (assuming you have created an imported a form `RecordForm` and a model `Record`, imported `get_object_or_404` and `redirect`):

```
@render_to('sometemplate.html')
def update(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        record = get_object_or_404(Record, pk=pk)
    else:
        record = None

    if request.POST:
        form = RecordForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('somepage')
        else:
            // ....
    elif record:
        form = RecordForm(instance=record)
    else:
        form = RecordForm()

    return { 'form': form, 'record': record }
```

I also integrate the messages framework to for example add an error message when form.is_valid() is False.

I use a render_to decorator but that's not necessary (but then you have to return the view results differently).

Comment: I would beg to differ. Class-based views are an excellent, DRY solution for many common use-cases. In my opinion function-based views should only be used for the few complicated use-cases where class-based views would actually over-complicate your code.

Comment: At first CBV's seem like a great solution for simple websites. But in my experience, simple websites never stay simple (the client's wishes...) and then it can become a nightmare to work with CBV's. A (for the client) seemingly simple adjustment can be a difficult adjustment with CBV's. Read [this](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/djangos-cbvs-were-a-mistake/) for more detailed examples where CBV's simplicity often isn't so simple in practice.

Comment: I use CBVs for most views, without any problems. The most sincere issues raised in that article are either avoidable with proper understanding of CBVs or completely wrong (e.g. `MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin` is just an extension of `TemplateResponseMixin` and has nothing to do with `MultipleObjectMixin`. `MOTRM` and `MOM` work together perfectly to create the `ListView` class.) Not to say there are no issues, but this article is exaggerating. However, I don't want/need to convince you, my intent is to prevent people reading your answer from dismissing CBVs without further thought.

Comment: He is not asking about how to use CBV's, but if CBV's is the way to go. And íf it is the way to go, how can it be implemented in his case. You say it is the way to go, I do not agree, and it's up to the reader to decide whether to use CBV's. So I don't understand your downvote.

Comment: Oh, I didn't downvote your answer, someone else did. Both our answers are equally valid, even thought I don't agree personally. Here, have an upvote to counteract that downvote for a perfectly valid answer :)

Comment: Thanks very much for both of your input. Its good hear the pros and cons of both to get a better understanding of how and why.